# Migration Issues with Win7

Tags: windows, windows-7, migration, clone, data-migration

I have a Windows 7 box that I am trying to migrate over to another box. I tried using Acronis and I ended up with not being able to boot Windows.

```
Error: 0xc000000f
The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

Is this a hardware issue? How can I better move this Windows 7 box off to another system?

Also, the windows boot disk does nothing to repair or fix the issue.

Comment: Are you sure the machine is the same? Did the original have a restore partition? Does the new one?

Comment: The machines are not the same. This is an upgraded machine. I did a backup with Acronis and then used the boot disk to do a restore.

Comment: I'm just wondering if it is trying to say boot from D:\, you need to have the same sort of partition layout on both machines..

Comment: I am assuming that is copied and kept the partitions and drive names all the same. But I can double check it when I am back in the lab later today and see if maybe that is related to the problem. I would have assumed that it would have wiped the drive/partitions and copied over the .TIB image to the full drive.

Comment: You could probably pop in a repair disc and have Windows fix it. This is commonly caused by the partition not being marked bootable which Acronis may not have done for you.

Comment: I tried that. No luck.

Comment: This is definitely off-topic for serverfault, but did you do a Hardware Independent Restore?